# TinyMCE4 paste from MS word

Tags: tinymce-4

I've tried pasting the data from MS word to TinyMCE4 but, I'm not retained with the same format as MS word, either font size will be reduced/increased or table will not be displayed or pasted image will not be shown.

I am using paste_retain_style_properties: "all",

and using getContent(). to get html from TinyMCE and passing the html to a contentEditableDiv. 
it keeps all the properties except the Table border.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set

```
valid_elements : "*[*]"
```

in the init function of tinyMCE?

If you want to add pictures they must be available on your server or they won't be shown online. So be sure to upload them and insert them with the path where the pictures are saved. Also not every style in MS Word can be transfered to HTML because MS Word sometimes uses special tags and styles.

I hope this helps a little bit.